# Filter Query with Django-Filter but Return Custom JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to be able to pass a query via an endpoint (such as `/api/generate-team/?rarity=Gold`), have that filter a queryset and then return custom JSON based on some calculations that occur.

Essentially, the query will contain filtered data from the `PlayerProfile` model. Data from the `PlayerProfile`'s is then calculated and a custom JSON response is returned.

I already have a `FilterSet` built for another view that contains that exact same filters we need, so I'd like to reuse it.

Here is a condensed version of the filter (this filter works great with the other view I'm using it for):

```
class PlayerProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    rarity = CharInFilter(field_name='rarity', lookup_expr='in')
    card_id = CharInFilter(field_name='card_id', lookup_expr='in')
    max_overall = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='overall', lookup_expr='lte')
 ...

class Meta:
    model = PlayerProfile
```

This is what I'm trying to do with the view:

```
class GenerateRosterView(some-kinda-viewset):
    queryset = PlayerProfile.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter,)
    filterset_class = PlayerProfileFilter

    def do_some_calculations_to_filtered_query_set():
        doSomething(queryset)
        return {"calculations": 1}
```

I'm having issues passing a filtered query to a function and returning a custom JSON response.

Comment: What do you mean by `some-kinda-viewset`? Maybe you need just an ordinary `APIView` from `rest_framework.views`?

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, hope it helps you -

```
def get_queryset(self):
    fromUrl == self.request.GET.get('rarity') # get queryparameter from url
    if fromUrl is None:
        #queryset = anyModel.objects.all()
        queryset = anyModel.objects.none()
    else:
        queryset = anyModel.objects.filter(anyData = fromUrl)
     return queryset
```

Edits -

well I was reading how to access class members and came to know about

```
class GenerateRosterView(some-kinda-viewset):
    queryset = PlayerProfile.objects.all()

    def do_some_calculations_to_filtered_query_set(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        ## and now access class members
        reqQuery= cls.queryset
```

give it a try.

Comment: This would work. But would require recreating all of the filters that already exist in the `PlayerProfileFilter` filterSet.

Comment: even if we define filter_backends and filterset_class at class level, writing a get method of views doesn't provide a filtered result. we have to again define filter conditions in our get method. I'm talking about ModalViewset. I'm not sure if you will receive filtered queryset in your do_some_calculations_to_filtered_query_set method but do write here if it works.